# reading a image file with imread in matlab gives what kind of representation?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, file-io

I am newbie on matlab and doing some little image processing tasks. I am using imread to read some images but I don't get after reading the image what kind of representation is given. Is it a binary representation of histogram of the image?

If someone might describe me I'll be appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [imread](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/imread.html):

> The return value A is an array containing the image data. If the file contains a grayscale image, A is an M-by-N array. If the file contains a truecolor image, A is an M-by-N-by-3 array. For TIFF files containing color images that use the CMYK color space, A is an M-by-N-by-4 array. See TIFF in the Format-Specific Information section for more information.

So it's an array, as your image also is an array of pixels.

Btw: it doesn't hurt to try things out for yourself...